# Highlight field which has a passed due date in google drive spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I calculated a due date based on Column A with EOMONTH (Column A, 3). The resulted dates are in Column B.

What I cannot achieve is to highlight the fields which are older than the current day.

In this way, I know which items should get updated.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Actually, this was quite easy using conditional formatting: date is before -> today

Comment: if you've answered this yourself, please share the knowledge by posting as an answer, thanks!

Comment: @AaronThomas I tried but it did not let me as I do not have enough reputation. I could only post a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

select your data in column `B`

click on the `Home` tab then `Conditional Formatting` » `Highlight Cells Rules` » `Less Than`

[image]

then type `=TODAY()` in the formula box

[image]

This will highlight any date that's older than today